# How to add play/pause button for (multiple) two different bootstrap 5 carousels

Tags: javascript, html, carousel, bootstrap-5

I have looked at other examples on stack overflow, trying to add these carousel controls and I am able to use one of the carousel controls on my page, but then the other set of controls will not work.

This is what I currently have.

```
        $(function() {
            $('#keynoteSpeakersCarouselPlayButton').click(function() {
                $(this).closest('.carousel').carousel('cycle');
            });
            $('#keynoteSpeakersCarouselPauseButton').click(function() {
                $(this).closest('.carousel').carousel('pause');
            });
            $('#sponsoredStreamsCarouselPlayButton').click(function() {
                $(this).closest('.carousel').carousel('cycle');
            });
            $('#sponsoredStreamsCarouselPauseButton').click(function() {
                $(this).closest('.carousel').carousel('pause');
            });
        });
```

I would think the solution would not work with jQuery

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding of the bootstrap carousel a method will be ignored if it is in the middle of a transition. You need to add an event listener and do your pause inside of that. I would set a flag, check for it inside of the event listener and then reset the flag. Also I would add IDs to each carousel to make it more straight forward to select. Something like what follows:

```
let flagPause = false;
let flagResume = false;

const carousel1 = document.getElementById('carousel1id');
carousel1.addEventListener('slid.bs.carousel', function() {
    if (flagPause == true) {
        carousel1.carousel('pause');
        flagPause = false;
    }
    if (flagResume == true) {
        carousel1.carousel('cycle');
        flagResume = false;
    }
});
$('#keynoteSpeakersCarouselPlayButton').click(function() {
    flagResume = true;
});
$('#keynoteSpeakersCarouselPauseButton').click(function() {
   flagPause = true;
});
```